# Will htaccess Options -Indexes prevent spiders and search engines from crawling files in directory?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Will setting an htaccess file with Options -Indexes prevent spiders and search engines from crawling the files in those directories?

Does simply having an index.html or index.php in a directory prevent the directory from being crawled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answers:**

> Will setting an htaccess file with `Options -Indexes` prevent spiders and search engines from crawling the files in those directories?

No it won't stop all the spiders & crawlers etc because `Options -Indexes` merely prevents directory listing when default `index` file is not present in a directory.

> Does simply having an index.html or index.php in a directory prevent the directory from being crawled?

Yes you need to have `index.php` or `index.html` with appropriate `DirectoryIndex` directive to make that index file as default file when directory is requested in a web request like this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
```

This makes `index.php` default index file and if that is not present then `index.html` will be used a default.

Comment: Would be interesting to know how a spider/crawler can get directory listing when Options -Indexes is set AND there is no DirectoryIndex file.

Comment: Spiders can only follow links so directory listing will not be cached by crawlers but other files can be indexed by following links.